# Link parameters in mailing removed

Tags: 2011, outbound-email

I wrote a TBB that adds some parameters to existing links in the output. These parameters are inserted at the end of each "href" attribute. This works fine when I preview the page, but in the mailing the parameters get removed. This only seems to happen when I use the "GetLinkTrackingURL" function. Parameters added directly in the DWT don't get removed, only the ones I add via the TBB. The DWT code looks like this:

```
<a href="@@GetLinkTrackingURL('tcm:95-52882-64','Some Text')@@&news=@@Component.ID@@">
```

When I preview the page I get:

```
<a href="tcm:95-52882-64&news=tcm:95-102627**&utm_source=test_mm&utm_medium=Test&utm_campaign=Test**">
```

When I test the mailing I get:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/redirect.jsp?a=L&amp;p=$f22Lb4IWoR3gOTiTDRvjVes3akqNvDz_8xVUPnLoLi0xJKye3bPEe4$$&news=tcm:95-102627">
```

The TBB is inserted in the page template after "Outbound E-mail Post-processing" ("Track Links" is set to "No"). It simply searches for "href" attributes in the output and inserts the parameters at the end of the link. I also tried to put it before "Outbound E-Mail Post-processing" and on the last position (after "Default Finish Actions"), but that also didn't work. How can I prevent that these parameters get removed when sending (or testing) the mail?

BTW: I'm using Tridion 2011 SP1-1.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the problem. When the page is rendered for the mailing the Link gets transformed to something like this:

```
[*__Link__ uri='tcm:95-52882-64' title='Some text'*]&news=tcm:95-102627
```

I needed to adjust my TBB to search for this pattern instead, to get it working for the mailing.